# sendSynchronousRequest blocked app?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

This method used to perform well, but today it's strange where app is blocked. I can't check its status or sth. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the idea with `synchronous` requests. If you want a non blocking operation either use an `asynchronous` request or a `synchronous` in another thread (not your main thread). If you need further clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks~ Synchronous request does have risk of blocking the main thread. It will not block app for an obvious wait in my normal case, so I simply ignored it. Yes, exception makes app better...

Answer (score 1):

whenevery you use a synchronous request or core data opertaion. remember to run it in background thread because it will halt your UI

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateData) withObject:nil];

Answer (score 1):

You Should send an Asynchronous request... It won't affect the UI and will run in the background. For Example:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

This request runs in the background and the data can be received and processed using the delegate methods mentioned below.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Since the UI works on the Main thread, so the UI will not be blocked.